# Do I need create new simple entity for query without join in jooq?

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

I have some entity that look like that:

```
data class ComplexEntity(
   private val id: UUID,
   private val srcSomethingId: UUID,
   private val dstSomethingId: UUID,
   private val creationDate: LocalDateTime,
   private val updatingDate: LocalDateTime?,
   private val creationAuthorId: UUID,
   private val updatingAuthorId: UUID?,
   private val roles: List<UUID>,
   private val fieldsId: UUID,
   // relation
   private val srcSomething: SomethingEntity?,
   private val dstSomething: SomethingEntity?
)
```

It has relation and i'm joining it with another table, but I don't need the relation most of the time, so maybe I need to create more simplified entity like projection or just stay relation fields `null` when they are not needed.

```
data class ComplexProjection (
   private val id: UUID,
   private val srcSomethingId: UUID,
   private val dstSomethingId: UUID,
   private val creationDate: LocalDateTime,
   private val updatingDate: LocalDateTime?,
   private val creationAuthorId: UUID,
   private val updatingAuthorId: UUID?,
   private val roles: List<UUID>,
   private val fieldsId: UUID
)
```

Or vice versa stay `ComplexProjection` like main entity because it need most of the time and call it `ComplexEntity` and make `ComplexEntityWithRelations` where put relations.

**What is the best way to do it?**

*P.S. Actually, I don't need all of this fields most of the times, but I think additional 5 field don't hurt performance so much.*

Comment: jOOQ doesn't have too much of an opinion related to how you model your data in your client code, if that's what your question is about. It can map to any data structure of your choice...

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, I understand that. But what are the best practices? I think it's common problem. When we using JPA we have lazy-fields to not select relation when it doesn't need, how in jooq better solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. What best practices? You can project anything in any way you want for any particular purpose. jOOQ would never tell you what to do, ideally. Your question has many solutions. It's not clear at all what you need your data for, so why would generic advice be suitable for your specific case? E.g. if you're using the reflective `DefaultRecordMapper`, it will map only those things that are available by convention. If you're writing your own mapper, you can do that explicitly.

Comment: @LukasEder I understand that I can do anything with jOOQ, it's more about architecture. I thought there was best practices for entity-layer. In JPA case we have one solution, just use complex entity with lazy-fields and use projections when you need it, but in jOOQ case we have three(or even more) solutions and it's cool, but I don't know how to do it better. By the way, thank you for jOOQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA entities are a way of modelling your data, similar to `CREATE TABLE` in SQL. If you normalise things reasonably, indeed, you don't have too many options, both in the form of SQL and in the form of JPA entities.

But, for all the wrong reasons, people also *project* those entities all the time, even if with JPA, you can project arbitrary data structures, just like with jOOQ. Your `data classes` aren't entities, they're projections. It's not the same thing. Like in SQL, where you can write arbitrary views for your data, and SQL wouldn't tell you to do it this or that way, jOOQ has no opinion about your *projections*.

So, the process is this:

1. Normalise your schema to a sufficient level (e.g. 3NF)
2. Design your queries according to your needs (e.g. the UI needs these 3 columns from table A and these 2 nested collections from table B)

That's it. The best query and thus the best projection for your individual needs arise naturally, from your (team's) preferences, your data representation, requirements, etc. There's no right or wrong projection of your data, as long as you can represent things in a reasonable way.

Comment: Do you wanna say that entity-layer is useless? And just use dto-data classes and use one with relations when they need to and one without (for individual needs). For some reason I thought that it's right to have immutable structure to project the hole table (even if some fields doesn't used)

Comment: Personally, I'd just tear it all down: https://blog.jooq.org/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead. But that's just me, and this isn't going to be very objective, so not a good fit for Stack Overflow.